# Flutter: Add custom widget periodically to GridView that doesn't fit its specifications

Tags: flutter, gridview, widget, ads

I want to have a GridView in Flutter with a crossAxisCount of to but periodically show a widget that takes up the whole width (an advertisement banner). How can I do that with a GridView?

Here is my code where I want to incorporate ad banners for every 10th row or so:

```
GridView.count(
    childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.05,
    controller: _scrollController,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: widgetList.map((value) {
      return value;
    }).toList(),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wrap instead of GridView.